Join google groups using link when entering link always redirects to the wrong account
I am trying to join a google group from a link, but when I pull up the link it always redirects to the wrong account. I can navigate Google groups with the right account, but then there's no way to type in the name of the group and join. You need the URL.

Log out of all accounts and then login to the right one
(not possible on desktop) log out of only wrong account and hope next
priority is the right one in the case you have >2 accounts like I do
Login to the right account in incognito and then enter link

I went with incognito solution. Is there any better way?

Active Profile Drives Navigation
By default, all navigation requests in Chrome are performed on behalf of the account associated with the active profile.
This doesn't change if the navigation is initiated from one Google web app to another, even if the Google app is logged into as a different user.
Two Solutions

Switch Chrome profile
Switch prior to pasting your link in the address bar.
Profile picture > Other profiles > other_account

Modify URL to specify saved Google user
If supported, modify the URL to access the Google app with a different Google user saved in your browser. NB: This will not change the active Chrome profile. Example URL: https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community

By email address https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community?authuser=joeblo@gmail.com

By saved user order (eg. 2) https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community?authuser=2
 or 
https://groups.google.com/u/2/g/google-apps-script-community




Chrome Active Profile
In Chrome, the active profile picture is displayed to the right of the address bar on all sites:
Non-Google Site  ( WebApps SE )

Google Site  ( Gmail )

Google Web App User
Google web apps, such as Gmail, Search, Calendar, display the logged in user picture at the top right of the web page which is below the active profile picture. The similar pictures located next to each other can be confusing.

Matching Accounts
B is logged in to both Chrome and Gmail. Navigation behaves as expected.

Different Accounts
B is logged in to Chrome, but O to Gmail. Navigating to a Google app from an email link, bookmark, or manually entered URL will be done on behalf of account B 



Active profile idea doesn't work. My active is always the intended account, reason it switches to other account when I access Google Groups is probably because the older account is default for GG, which I guess is because I used GG on it first. I will try the other ideas.

@Displayname I don't understand that. I'm wondering if the URL already has /u/#/ or similar account identifier already embedded in it which tracks to the wrong account in normal mode, but in Incognito it works because it's unmatched so it reverts to the default account 0. Also, it's worth noting that each Chrome profile has its own list of saved Google App users and in that case switching Chrome profiles might not resolve the problem if it maps incorrectly. It would be helpful if you shared the URL to see if it offers any clues.

@Displayname Also, if one of the approaches works let us know which one

I thought this was the case but it's not. I have 3 accounts: default, A, B. Almost always, I use default or B since A is old. The URL I originally used is https://groups.google.com/u/1/a/B.edu/g/group-name, which redirected to A somehow. If I do https://groups.google.com/a/B.edu/g/group-name, now it redirects to my default. No matter what I do, I can't win with just modifying the URL.
Incognito works because I login with the account I want and it's forced to redirect there since I'm not using any other account.

Ok, it seems the number is what matters. Changing it to 0, 1, 2, 3, ... changes accounts. In essence, I rediscovered your "By saved user order" solution, which is by far the simplest. In case anyone with tons of accounts reads this, default is 0 and the rest are in the order that appears when you click on profile picture when using default gmail.
